# I want to display my custom post type arranged by taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy

Sorry New to this custom post and taxonomy thing
I want help in displaying my custom post type arranged by taxonomy.

The output would be like:

- Parent 1 Taxonomy Title

  - Child 1 Taxonomy Title

    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 1
    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 2
  - Child 2 Taxonomy Title

    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 1
    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 2
  - Child 3 Taxonomy Title

    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 1
    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 2
- Parent 1 Taxonomy Title

  - Child 1 Taxonomy Title

    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 1
    - Title of a Post Under Child Taxonomy 2

currently I'm using this code

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('material_category');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    wp_reset_query();
    $args = array('post_type' => 'materials',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'material_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('general-english')
            ),
        ),
     );

     $loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
        echo '<h2>'.$custom_term->name.'</h2>';

        while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a>';
        endwhile;
     }
```

But it displays the Parent separately.
Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're echoing the Parent term name outside of the loop.

```
$custom_terms = get_terms('material_category');

foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
    $args = array('post_type' => 'materials',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'material_category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => array('general-english')
            ),
        ),
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    if ($loop->have_posts()) {
        while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
            echo '<h2>' . $custom_term->name . '</h2>';
            echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';
        endwhile;
    }
    wp_reset_query();
}
```